# Creative A100 2.1 subwoofer not working

Tags: audio, speakers

I have an old model of Creative 2.1 speakers system, the model is A100. This is a PC speaker system which was working just fine till yesterday. My issue is, the subwoofer is not working but the two speakers are working fine (checked by connecting to my mobile device) but the sound outcome is ridiculously low.

When I directly connect the speakers to the PC, they are not producing any sound, already did tweaking through the realtek software but not success. I think the subwoofer acts as an amplifier or something like that so it gives very loud and good sound when connected to PC.

I have little to no knowledge regarding speakers but I want to use these speakers without subwoofer on my PC. Please tell me, what should I buy to use these speakers again and produce loud sound. Hope you understand my problem.

Comment: If the sub contains the amp, then to use just the satellites would require purchase of a new amp.